# Knex query returning undefined although the expected record exists in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I'm using knex for this query:

```
const transaction = knex('transactions').first()
      .where({
        customer_id: customerProduct.customerId,
        product_id: customerProduct.productId,
      })
      .orderBy('delivered', 'DESC');
```

It returns undefined for `transaction`. If I remove either `customer_id` or `product_id` it returns a record for transaction. All my data si setup correctly in the database. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The docs go as follows:

> first — .first([columns])
>   Similar to select, but only retrieves & resolves with the first record from the query.

`knex.table('users').first('id', 'name').then(function(row) { console.log(row); });`

you probably need to specify which columns you want to return i.e `first("*")`

I personally prefer to destructure in this case i.e `const [transaction] = await knex("transactions) etc...`